# Accidentally deleted .bashrc on USB stick Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, bashrc

I have a 16GB flash drive I have setup to run Ubuntu 12.04 from. While using it, I accidentally deleted .bashrc, and rebooted the system not realizing the file was gone. Now Ubuntu just hangs on the load.

I have setup another flash drive with 13.10, in an attempt to mount the 12.04 flash drive and add the .bashrc file back in. When I mount the drive, my HOME directory where .bashrc would live, is not there. I did some research and found that most likely the directories are encrypted, and ran through the "Recovering your data automatically" step of this post:

```
  <https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering%20Your%20Data%20Manually>
```

But after running `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/usb` successfully, nothing changed in the mounted drive. How can I get to my HOME directory to add the .bashrc file back in so I can boot this drive again?

Comment: The `.bashrc` file is generated automatically each time you log in. There isn't a reason why your session should hang. Please, when you boot switch to a TTY (press Ctrl+Alt+F2) then copy the contents of `~/.xsession-errors` and paste them here.

Comment: Thanks, the output is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E9dpsPBBVbAnr5xjK6sOHVxTyQw5ZInGmIC7qE25kyc/edit

Comment: Could you upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com?

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6264122/ Sorry, I am knew to this forum. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, deleting `.bashrc` would not do that to your installation, it looks quite irrelevant; from [this](https://superuser.com/a/49292/216798) answer on superuser,

> When an interactive shell that is not
>   a login shell is started, bash reads
>   and executes commands from ~/.bashrc,
>   if that file exists. This may be
>   inhibited by using the --norc option.
>   The --rcfile file option will force
>   bash to read and execute commands from
>   file instead of ~/.bashrc.

so unless you are somehow opening a terminal on startup, you don't have to worry about your `.bashrc`, look for other problems with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Every Ubuntu OS will have some default configuration files in `/etc/skel` directory.

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo ls -a /etc/skel
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  examples.desktop  .profile  .Xdefaults  .xscreensaver
```

so if you would like to restore the default `.bashrc` file in your Ubuntu then simply copy it to your home directory,

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```